# I want to automatically plot my training accuracy but I use different accuracy metrics depending on the task. How can I access them in a generic way?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dictionary, keras

I built a Python framework to train my neural networks for image classification using Tensorflow/Keras.

To actually train the model I use this line of code:

`history = model.fit(dataset_train, validation_data=dataset_val, epochs=epochs)`

History (type: dict) contains the accuracies and losses for each epoch as lists and I want to plot them, so I wrote this function.

```
def plot_data(training_history, save_path):
    acc = training_history.history['accuracy']
    val_acc = training_history.history['val_accuracy']
    loss = training_history.history['loss']
    val_loss = training_history.history['val_loss']

    epochs_range = range(len(training_history.epoch))

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(epochs_range, acc, label='Training Accuracy')
    plt.plot(epochs_range, val_acc, label='Validation Accuracy')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.title('Training and Validaiton Accuracy')

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(epochs_range, loss, label='Training loss')
    plt.plot(epochs_range, val_loss, label='Validation Loss')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.title('Training and Validation Loss')
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_path, 'acc_loss.jpg'), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show(block=False)
```

It worked fine but now the issue is the following: For some tasks I need to use different metrics, such as categorical_accuracy. If I do that, the function doesn't work anymore because now I need to access `history['categorical_accurcay']` instead of `history['accuracy']`.

Is there an elegant, generic way to solve this problem? History always contains 4 elements: The training loss, the training accuracy, the validation loss and the validation accuracy but the keys change depending on my training setup and as far as I know, there is no way of using an index in a dict.

Comment: How exactly does the data change? Can't this be solved with supplying a keword argument for the key of the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over history dict keys, for example:

```py
def plot_data(training_history, save_path):
    epochs_range = range(len(training_history.epoch))

    plt.figure()

    for i, metric in enumerate(training_history.history.keys()):
        metric_values = training_history.history[metric]
        metric_values_val = training_history.history['val_' + metric]

        plt.subplot(1, len(history.keys()), i + 1)
        plt.plot(epochs_range, metric_values , label=f'Training {metric}')
        plt.plot(epochs_range, metric_values_val , label=f'Validation {metric}')
        plt.legend(loc='upper right')
        plt.title(f'Training and Validation {metric}')

    plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_path, 'metrics.jpg'), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show(block=False)
```